# What is the history of how a neutron moderator is chosen in nuclear chain reactions?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Maybe the wrong area...should be physics maybe...but there is some history here as well.  I became interested in knowing how Fermi came to pick graphite as a neutron moderator.

For example beryllium may be the moderator in a radium beryllium neutron source . I am interested in knowing what  the B reactor at the  Hanford Site used as a neutron source so naturally a history of how moderators were chosen is helpful. I know  graphite was a moderator for the uranium oxide at Hanford reactor B but then what was the moderator for the neutron source and even more interesting what was the neutron source to first start the chain reation, it would have to be something other than uranium oxide.

Now you see why I have this in the history section.  I assume some moderators are better than others so a historical perspective may be the best approach.

Comment: MIght want to read Rhodes' "Making of the Atomic Bomb."  IIRC graphite was somewhat easier to obtain in quantity and necessary purity.

Comment: Fission reactors (such as the Chicago pile and the Hanford B reactor) do not need a separate neutron source - spontaneous fission is sufficient to get them going. Then you want to moderate the resulting fission neutrons to lower energies to increase the cross-section for neutron-induced fission reactions (generally).